# iPhone 13 Pro / swift / AVFoundation builtInTripleCamera : how to enable automatic switching between cameras?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

I am currently making a custom camera app for iOS with swiftUI AVFoundation.
I also just bought iPhone 13 Pro.
On the native Camera App, cameras automatically switch depending on FOCUS (ultrawide for macro / wideangle for intermediate distance / telephoto when focusing on far objects).
This is also mentioned in documentation :

> The built-in triple camera supports the following features: Automatic
> switching from one camera to another when zoom factor, light level,
> and focus position allow.

How can I make this work in my custom app ?
This is how I am selecting the camera (virtual device) :

```
let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [ .builtInTripleCamera ], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
let cameras = (session.devices.compactMap { $0 })
for camera in cameras {
  if camera.position == .back {
    self.rearCamera = camera
    try camera.lockForConfiguration()
    camera.exposureMode = .continuousAutoExposure
    camera.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
    camera.unlockForConfiguration()
  }
}
```

Is there a configuration I am missing ?

Comment: I'm pretty out of the loop on new stuff, but have you looked at `AVCam`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app

Answer (score 13):

Once you start zooming in, either by directly setting the [`videoZoomFactor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624611-videozoomfactor) or by calling the [`ramp(toVideoZoomFactor:withRate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624614-ramp) method for the input device, it automatically switches between the Ultrawide, Wide-angle and Telephoto lens. The switch happens based on the zoom factor being set.

A zoom factor of **1** is always the minimum. In case of the 13 Pro, setting a zoom factor of **1** will switch to the Ultrawide lens. To know which are the other zoom factors at which the system decides to switch over to the next lens, you can take a look at the [`virtualDeviceSwitchOverVideoZoomFactors`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/3153003-virtualdeviceswitchovervideozoom) property of the capture device. In case of the 13 Pro, it is **2** and **6**. At **2**, it will switch over to the Wide-angle lens. At **6**, it will switch over to the Telephoto lens.

You need not set any other configuration for this to work out, as long as you are using the `.builtInTripleCamera` device type.

Comment: This is works well! Thank you very much Vishal!